# CCLabelBMFont cannot seem to find the font file?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using cocos-builder to create my view which contains a CCLabelBMFont, the font is set correctly in cocos-builder. But each time I run the app it crashes in the `setFntFlie:` because it isn't able to find the font file.
I've checked my simulator and it contains the `.fnt` and `.png` files.

Any ideas?

---

Ok so I figured out that the problem is with **cocos-builder**. For some weird reason it isn't able to find the font files in the bundle, but if I use `CCLabelBMFont` directly it works fine. Any ideas on why cocos-builder behaves weirdly ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether the membership of these files are included in the target.

1. Select file on right side pane.

2. Select the target.

[image]

Comment: The files are included in the target. I'm able to see both of the files in my simulator folder.

Comment: here it is :  
CCLabelBMFont:Impossible to create font. Please check file: 'Fonts/***.fnt'    
"4   temp  0x003f590a -[CCLabelBMFont setFntFile:] + 250",  
This is where it crashes, some debugging showed that it isn't able to find the font file